# Problem with fsevents dependency while trying to install tailwindcss on linux

Tags: linux, tailwind-css, fsevents

I'm trying to install tailwindcss in my Vue Js project using the following command:

> ```
> npm install -D tailwindcss@latest
> ```

But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

There is a related topic [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935) where the proposed solution is to set ***fsevents*** as *devDependencies* but it is not possible in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -D -f tailwindcss@latest` this forced the installation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing tailwind in my reactjs application. I could resolve the error by `npm install -D -f tailwindcss@latest`.